# PHP Session just working when opening another page

Tags: php, session

I have a very weird problem that i never had before.
I created a login.php where you can login via a form.
When everything is good (password username) the session `$_SESSION["login"]` gets the name of the user.

I run that script and it wasnt working (the session was still empty). 
To check if the session is working I added:

```
echo "session: ".$_SESSION["test"];
$_SESSION["test"] = "test";
echo "nosession: ".$_SESSION["test"];
```

And it allways said: "session: nosession: test"
Because of this i knew the session doesn't seem to work.
Then I created another page: session.php
with just THAT:

```
session_start();
echo "session: ".$_SESSION["ses"];
$_SESSION["ses"] = "test";
echo "nosession: ".$_SESSION["ses"];
```

When i opened and reloaded the page i was able to read:
"session: testnosession: test"

This means, that the session seems to work (no server problem)
After i opened the session.php, i opened the login.php and reloaded the page. AND THEN IT SAID: 
"session: testnosession: test"

and i also was able to login.

This means i am just able to login if i opened another php script that creates a completly different session.

Does anyone knows what is happening here?

**EDIT:**
Even when i delete the complete PHP code (login.php) and just add

```
session_start();
echo "session: ".$_SESSION["test"];
$_SESSION["test"] = "test";
echo "nosession: ".$_SESSION["test"];
```

ITS STILL NOT WORKING!!!

maybe it's because of UTF-8 in meta tag?

**EDIT**

Just writing all the code on a new .php worked. It had to be an error in the file that was not visible

Comment: you need everytime at first your session_start()

Comment: I did and now i deleted every php code exept the 4 lines session. and its still not working.

Comment: What is your output from session_id()? Is it changed after a reload?

Comment: Print the session like this print_r($_Session)

Comment: And check session is working or not and also check the session print or not.?

Comment: **print_r...** same problem **session_id** it allways change when reloading, but not if i open session.php first (thats when sessions are working like i said before)

Comment: Is there PHPSESSIONID header in response?

Comment: Is there something like this in request or response headers?
 Cookie:PHPSESSID=ebfd388amcrl1bca10a6lc1km1

Comment: So, your PHP script should create session ID and set this id into cookies. Your browser should remember this value and sent it to your server back with each request. Is it happen?

Comment: Read how session work

Comment: there is one and its named LCWSID it has the same code as my session_id()

Comment: **edit** its not set until i open seesion.php